# Pearson Correlation has quizzy results

Tags: statistical-significance, pearson-r

I investigated experiments with SPSS and following values were out.

I have a question that in which case is possible to get **Feature 1 in Group A+B as significant p<.05** while either Group A and B has low significance in Feature 1?

I hardly interpret because Group A have low correlation and Group B also, but combined group have correlation with (very) high significance.

[image]

(* p<.05)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you have a simple example with made-up data: there are two groups $A$ and $B$ and two variables $X$ and $Y$. In both groups alone the correlation of $X$ and $Y$ are small (*r* = -.17 and .23), but if you combine them you see a linear trend (*r* = .67).

[image]

So, as you can see, this kind of relation is possible. Local relations (or lack of them) is not the same as global relations. You can [read more](http://jech.bmj.com/content/56/8/588.full) on atomistic fallacy and ecological fallacy - i.e. logical errors when drawing conclusions on groups based on individual level data or individuals based on group level data.

Comment: Simpson's paradox is related. One statement is that amalgamation of subsets can result in changed magnitude and even sign of relationships.

Comment: Hi Tim, I think `X` and `Y`  means random variable, it is clear, and what means `group` here? Like group `A` and group `B`?

Comment: And you said "combine them", what exactly you do for `combine`?

Comment: @LinMa X,Y are r.v. (on x- and y- axis of the plots). A,B are groups. By saying that I "combine" them I mean that I look at all of the data (third plot) ignoring the grouping.

Comment: Thanks Tim, what means groups here? I think in order to do Pearson's r square analysis, we just need two one dimension random variable?

Comment: @LinMa groups are groups as in the question.

Comment: Thanks Tim, read the question and analysis again, and still feel confused about group here. I think X and Y are two random variable, and we draw its joint probability distribution in the plots here, it seems X and Y behaves different according to `group`? Is `group` some other random variable? And what means `+` in group A+B?

Comment: Imagine you have two tests X and Y (say on mathematics and English), two groups of students A and B made the tests (say two classes). You can look at the test results taken together (A+B) or on results for each of the classes alone.