# Analysis of many companies over a period

Tags: regression

I'm trying to see the relationship between some variables, for example, with the model below

$$\text{Profitability} = \varepsilon + \beta_0 + \beta_1 \text{DoL} + \beta_2 \text{DFL} + \beta_3 \text{SZ}$$

with:
DoL = Degree of Operating Leverage
DFL = Degree of Financial Leverage
SZ = Firm size

and those data are taken from financial statements
However, I don't know how to perform the regression analysis because I have data of many companies, and for each companies, I have data for 10 years. So i'm not sure should I use the average of all companies (this will become the sector) for each year, or should I run the regression with average of each company over the period.

Answer (score 1):

Averaging over companies is a *bad* idea and could lead you to biased results because it would lead you to use group-level (averaged results) and individual-level results as the same while they *are* different entities (see an example in [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125683/pearson-correlation-has-quizzy-results/125686#125686)).

The valid approach would be to use a multilevel model where where time is nested in companies. So simplifying it is:

$$ y_{ij} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_{1ij} + ... + \beta_k X_{kij} + b_i + \varepsilon_{ij} $$

where $\beta$ are fixed effects, $b_i$ is random intercept for each of the $i$'th companies and $j$ is an index of time. Different models are also possible, for example with random slopes.

This kind of models are implemented in multiple software, including the great `lme4` package for R.

You can read more for example in:

- Snijders, T.A.B. & Bosker, R.J. (2012). *Multilevel Analysis: An Introduction to Basic and Advanced Multilevel Modeling*. London: Sage Publishers.
- Hox, J. (2010). *Multilevel Analysis: Techniques and Applications*. New York: Routledge.
- Gelman, A. & Hill, J. (2006). *[Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/)*. Cambridge University Press.

Comment: Please let me know your thoughts on this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/408031/how-to-convert-classification-features-into-a-ranking-function I look forward to hearing from you. Thank you very much :)