# Is it logical to look for a correlation between average and percentage?

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, data-transformation

I have a simple question. Can one look for correlations between percentage and average ? For example,  percentage of unemployment and average salary. Or shoul I use total numbers instead ? If  I look for a relation between percentages and average I get significant correlation, but between totals data is not significant.

Comment: Usually, when looking for correlations, it is an attempt to define cause and effect relationships.  I can find correlations between the date of the year and my check number, but the fact both increase sequentially is rather expected.  There is also a significant correlation between pirates and global warming, but there is (to my knowledge) no cause and effect relationship between the data.

Comment: @subhashc.davar My variables are percentages of unemployed people in state every month and average salary of employed people in state every month. So I have unemployment data from bureau of statistics USA and average salary is calculated from randomly selected 10K people in that state.

Comment: @subhashc.davar Correct

Answer (score 2):

The biggest risk of looking at statistics of the aggregates is [ecological fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecological_fallacy) ([example here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/125686/35989)). Group-level aggregates do not necessarily are suitable for inferring individual-level characteristics. The most vivid example is the [Simpson's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox), which shows how you can get completely different results when looking at group-level vs individual-level data. If you only have the aggregated data, your results do not necessarily translate to the individuals.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be really uncomfortable with a correlation between a(n average of) continuous variable and a percentage, because the percentage is bounded by $[0,100]$. So if the percentage is near these boundaries, the relation (i.e. correlation) between the two is bound to be non-linear. A more suitable way of associating one continuous and a categorical variable is, for example, through regression.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't thought that percentages are categorical variable so I used Pearson method to calculate correlation.  But I do not understand why percentages are categorical variable ?

Comment: Most often a percentage is calculated by grouping in some way (e.g. the proportion of men out of the total sample). I assumed this is what you meant. But I must admit, sometimes a percentage is used to show change from a certain baseline point (e.g. my income has changed by 150%). This second case is slightly different because in this case the percentage is bounded only on the lower side ([$0,∞]$), but still the problem of non-linearity remains, especially if you include '100%' as the neutral (no-change) point.

Comment: Now I understand why my data is categorical, that you for explanation.